# How to handle single SelectedIndexChanged event to multiple ComboBox using C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 8 `ComboBox` that have similar `SelectedIndexChanged` block that stores a `List` of `string` and `combobox`.

```
private void cmbPItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPItem.Text };
    List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
    cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
}

private void cmbPBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Brand", "Item", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPBrand.Text };
    List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
    cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
}

private void cmbPPart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Part No.", "Item", "Brand", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPPart.Text };
    List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
    cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
}
```

These are the 3 sample blocks of my event, there are 5 more having same block but different arrangement. The stored `List` must be in the correct order to pass in the `cmbValue` function.

Now I change it to a single event with if statement

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbPItem.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPItem.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPBrand.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Brand", "Item", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPBrand.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPPart.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Part No.", "Item", "Brand", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPPart.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPDesc.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Description", "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPDesc.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPMan.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Manufacturer", "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Car", "Year", "Made In", cmbPItem.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPCar, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPCar.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Car", "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Year", "Made In", cmbPCar.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPYr, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPYr.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Year", "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Made In", cmbPYr.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPMade };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
    if (cmbPMade.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        List<string> srchtxt = new List<string> { "Made In", "Item", "Brand", "Part No.", "Description", "Manufacturer", "Car", "Year", cmbPMade.Text };
        List<ComboBox> cmb = new List<ComboBox> { cmbPItem, cmbPBrand, cmbPPart, cmbPDesc, cmbPMan, cmbPCar, cmbPYr };
        cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify it to make it more neat and easier to read. Since there is a possibility to add more `ComboBox`

Comment: Yes it is a way to simplify it, actually a lot of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sender` object to determine which combobox triggered the event. Also, you can use tuples and LINQ to clean this up a lot:

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<(ComboBox Cmb, string Text)> items = new List<(ComboBox, string)
    {
        (cmpItem, "Item"), (cmbPBrand, "Brand"), (cmbPPart, "Part No."),
        (cmbPDesc, "Description"), (cmbPMan, "Manufacturer"), (cmbPCar, "Car"),
        (cmbPYr, "Year"), (cmbPMade, "Made In")
    };

    List<string> srchtxt = (new[] { items.First(i => i.Cmb == sender).Text })
        .Concat(items.Where(i => i.Cmb != sender).Select(i => i.Text))
        .ToList();

    List<ComboBox> cmb = items
        .Where(i => i.Cmb != sender)
        .Select(i => i.Cmb)
        .ToList();

    cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added `ComboBox cbx = (ComboBox)sender;` and change `cmbValue(srchtxt, cmb, cbx.Text);`. Since I can't figure out how to  pass the `ComboBox` sender text. Sorry this is my first time to read `Tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all comboboxes in a list, and would store it in a member variable of the from.
Then you can put the names in srchtxt into the comboboxes Tag property.
Then loop thru all comboboxes, and generate the srchtxt by using `new ComboBox[] { current }.Union(comboboxes.Where(x => x != current)).Select(x => x.Tag as string).Union(new string [] { current.Text }).ToList()` and you get a list that looks pretty much like the lists you created hard coded in your post.